# error on running raw sql query in upgradeData.php magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, sql, setup-script

I have created my own module and in **`UpgradeData.php`** script I am writing my own, **`mysql query`** but it gives me an error when I run **`bin/magento setup:upgrade`** to run the setup script files

> Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql could not be converted to string in /Users/suman/the-webster/app/code/YX/Migration/Setup/UpgradeData.php on line 51

The **mysql query** I am trying is:

> $sequence_value =  $setup->getConnection()->query("SELECT max(sequence_value)+1 FROM `sequence_cms_block`");

What am I doing wrong

full class code

```
<?php
namespace YX\Migration\Setup;
/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */

public function 
upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface$setup,ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

// if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.3', '<')) {

        $table_sequence_cms_block = $setup->getTable('sequence_cms_block');
        $table_cms_block  = $setup->getTable('cms_block');
        $table_cms_block_store  = $setup->getTable('cms_block_store');


        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->info("i am here before sequence_value query8 ");

        $sequence_value =  $setup->getConnection()->query("SELECT max(sequence_value)+1 FROM `sequence_cms_block`");

        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->info("i am here after sequence_value query8 ".$sequence_value);

        $cms_block_query = "INSERT INTO `cms_block` (`block_id`,`created_in`,`updated_in`,`title`,`identifier`,`content`,`creation_time`,`update_time`,`is_active`) VALUES (" . $sequence_value . ",1,2147483647,'Footer Left Detail','footer_left_detail','<div class=\"col-lg-4\">
                                            <div class=\"left-parent-header\">
                                            THE WEBSTER
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"first-left-content\">
                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Contact Us</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">About</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Team</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Affiliates</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Press</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"col-lg-4\">
                                            <div class=\"left-parent-header\">
                                            STORE INFORMATION
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"third-left-content\">
                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">South Beach</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Soho</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Houston</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Bal Harbour</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Costa Mesa</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"col-lg-4\">
                                            <div class=\"left-parent-header\">
                                            SHOPPING ONLINE
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"second-left-content\">
                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Payment &amp; Security</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Shipping</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Return Policy</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">FAQ</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>',NOW(),NOW(),1);";

        $setup->getConnection()->query($cms_block_query);

        $row_id_query = "select row_id from cms_block where block_id = ".$sequence_value;
        $row_id =  $setup->getConnection()->query($row_id_query);

        $cms_block_store_query = "INSERT INTO `cms_block_store` (`row_id`,`store_id`) VALUES (" .$row_id. " ,1);";
        $setup->getConnection()->query($cms_block_store_query);



     //        }
     $setup->endSetup();
    } }
```

Comment: Add full class that you have tried

Comment: remove `$sequence_value`, write like this,  
  
$setup->getConnection()->query("SELECT max(sequence_value)+1 FROM sequence_cms_block");

Comment: don't put `$setup` to variable

Comment: @SohelRana added

Comment: @magefms but i need value of that select query, i have to use that value in insert of another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly query like this, I am suggesting to you use `Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory` oR `Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface` to create a static block.

if you will use this, then you no need to update or select the record of `sequence_cms_block` table.

***Code may like:**

```
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory
     */
    protected $blockFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,        
     )
    {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    }
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */

    public function  upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface$setup,ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $content = '<div class=\"col-lg-4\">
                                            <div class=\"left-parent-header\">
                                            THE WEBSTER
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"first-left-content\">
                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Contact Us</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">About</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Team</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Affiliates</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Press</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"col-lg-4\">
                                            <div class=\"left-parent-header\">
                                            STORE INFORMATION
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"third-left-content\">
                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">South Beach</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Soho</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Houston</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Bal Harbour</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Costa Mesa</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"col-lg-4\">
                                            <div class=\"left-parent-header\">
                                            SHOPPING ONLINE
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=\"second-left-content\">
                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Payment &amp; Security</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Shipping</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">Return Policy</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=\"#\">FAQ</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>';
        $block = $this->blockFactory->create();
        $block->setIdentifier('footer_left_detail')
                ->setTitle('Footer Left Detail')
                ->setContent($content);
        $block->setStores([\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID]);
        $block->setIsActive(1);
        $block->save();                
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, can you provide me some links for the same , how to use BlockFactory or BlockRepositoryInterface to create static block

Comment: Can i do it same for megamenu, as i have lots of queries for megamenu also

Comment: I don't  know how you have managed menu.So cannot tell you

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259806/how-to-add-a-megamenu-programmatically-in-magento-2

check this

Comment: I have added megamenu from my magento admin panel, now i have to replicate the same in my production via updateData scripts, I have added which tables gets updated

Answer (score 0):

Your query where the error occurs returns an object. You have to fetch the value and use that in your next statement.

```
$sequence_value = $setup->getConnection()->query("SELECT max(sequence_value)+1 FROM `sequence_cms_block`")->fetch(Zend_Db::FETCH_NUM);
```

`$sequence_value[0]` should contain the value you need.

Comment: It gives me this error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'YX\Migration\Setup\Zend_Db' not found in /Users/suman/the-webster/app/code/YX/Migration/Setup/UpgradeData.php:190

Comment: you have to put `use Zend_Db;` in the head of your file