# How to add a Megamenu programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, setup-script, install-script, megamenu

I need to add Megamenu via an install/upgrade script. I've added my `megamenu`. I've figured out which tables get updated when I add Megamenu.

The table which gets updated is

```
mgs_megamenu
mgs_megamenu_store
```

How can I achieve it programmatically like for cms block
I referred this link for cms block

> [How to add a CMS block programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127495/how-to-add-a-cms-block-programmatically-in-magento-2)

The queries which I prepared for megamenu, requires lots of `insert` and `select`

query1

```
INSERT INTO `mgs_megamenu` 
(`title`,`menu_type`,`category_id`,`position`,`columns`,
`dropdown_position`,`use_thumbnail`,`static_content`,
`left_col`,`right_col`,`status`,`parent_id`,`store`) VALUES 
('WHAT''S NEW',2,0,0,6,1,2,'<div class="mega-menu-content">
</div>',1,1,1,1,0);
```

query2

```
SET @mgs_megamenu_id = (SELECT max(megamenu_id) FROM mgs_megamenu);
```

query3

```
INSERT INTO `mgs_megamenu_store` (`megamenu_id`,`store_id`) VALUES (@mgs_megamenu_id ,0);
```

Modal class of MGS is 
   `MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category;`

Comment: Please share the Model class of  that module

Comment: Its a big file, so i have given the path